# Multiple indices on a table

Tags: sql-server, index, nonclustered-index

I have run SQL Profiler and I can see that I'm "missing" some indexes (non-clustered) on a table. How is it best to handle indexes that can be a "subset" of another index?

Index 1

```
UserId, InstanceId, Created
```

Index 2 (Subset of Index 1)

```
InstanceId, Created
```

Is index 2 necessary in this case?

Can't really found the query that caused **Index 2**

Query (using Entity framework):

```
SELECT 1 AS [C1], [Limit1].[InputForm] AS [InputForm], [Project2].[UserId] AS [UserId]
FROM (SELECT [Distinct1].[UserId] AS [UserId]
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId]
        FROM [dbo].[Dat_GameCompletionData] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[InstanceId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Created] >= @p__linq__1)
    )  AS [Distinct1] ) AS [Project2]
OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Project3].[InputForm] AS [InputForm]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent2].[InputForm] AS [InputForm], 
        [Extent2].[Created] AS [Created]
        FROM [dbo].[Dat_GameCompletionData] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Extent2].[InstanceId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent2].[Created] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Project2].[UserId] = [Extent2].[UserId])
    )  AS [Project3]
    ORDER BY [Project3].[Created] DESC ) AS [Limit1]
```

Comment: What is the query that misses index 1? Does it do an equality predicate on all three columns?

Comment: Non of the indexes exists now. Yes we are doing a equality predicate on all three columns.

Comment: So an index on `InstanceId, Created, UserId` would be equally good for query 1 and also satisfy query 2.

Comment: Can you provide the queries to determine if those indices were **really** necessary?

Comment: @Ionic One query added

Comment: The queries you've shown have a `>=` not `=` for all columns...

Comment: Yes, that's true. And how does affect the handling of indices?

Comment: With the classic Phone book example (composite index `lastname, firstname`) - Look for all people with lastname equal to "Smith" and later or equal than "Martin" is pretty easy but looking for people with lastname >= "Smith" and firstname="Martin" much less so.

Comment: Yes, and how does that affect how you should set up your index?

Comment: Well clearly you want to set up your index in the order that makes it easiest to satisfy your queries. i.e. colum with equality condition first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say that index 2 is a subset of index 1.

An index that had the columns `UserId, InstanceId` would be.

This could still be useful to queries that do not require the `created` column as they would be accessing a more narrow index which would require less IO and memory.

Your best bet is to check if your indexes are actually being used by queries. The scripts below will help with this.

```
SELECT  d.name as [Database]
        , OBJECT_NAME(S.[OBJECT_ID]) AS [OBJECT NAME]          
        , I.[NAME] AS [INDEX NAME]         
        , USER_SEEKS          
        , USER_SCANS        
        , USER_LOOKUPS          
        , USER_UPDATES 

FROM    SYS.DM_DB_INDEX_USAGE_STATS AS S          
JOIN    SYS.INDEXES AS I ON I.[OBJECT_ID] = S.[OBJECT_ID]               
                            AND I.INDEX_ID = S.INDEX_ID 
JOIN    sys.Databases d on s.database_id = d.database_id

WHERE    OBJECTPROPERTY(S.[OBJECT_ID],'IsUserTable') = 1 

ORDER BY USER_SEEKS + USER_SCANS + USER_LOOKUPS + USER_UPDATES DESC


SELECT  d.name
        , t.name
        , OBJECT_NAME(A.[OBJECT_ID]) AS [OBJECT NAME]
        , I.[NAME] AS [INDEX NAME]
        , A.LEAF_INSERT_COUNT        
        , A.LEAF_UPDATE_COUNT
        , A.LEAF_DELETE_COUNT

FROM    SYS.DM_DB_INDEX_OPERATIONAL_STATS (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL ) A        
JOIN    SYS.INDEXES AS I ON I.[OBJECT_ID] = A.[OBJECT_ID]   
JOIN    sys.tables t ON i.object_id = t.object_id      
JOIN    sys.databases d ON a.database_id = d.database_id
                        AND I.INDEX_ID = A.INDEX_ID 

WHERE   OBJECTPROPERTY(A.[OBJECT_ID],'IsUserTable') = 1

ORDER BY    A.LEAF_INSERT_COUNT + A.LEAF_UPDATE_COUNT + A.LEAF_DELETE_COUNT DESC
```

Comment: Those two queries do get reset when SQL Server is restarted.

Comment: In which way does the order of the column in index make sense?

Comment: @MarkSinkinson yes thats true so it's better to run these when the server has been up for a while.

Comment: @Rikard The first column in the index is the most important as this will dictate the main order of the index. The following columns order the data when the first column has the same value for multiple rows.

Comment: Okay, then it's often best to have the most unique value first then? But if I want to "reuse" an index then I have to think about the order.

Comment: Generally I would agree with that but as always it depends. What do you mean by reuse?

Comment: Instead of having two indices then have one more "general". An index like `InstanceId, Created, UserId` will also full fill queries only on InstanceId and Created as for UserId, InstanceId and Created.

Comment: Yes that's true and it may be the best solution here but you could also have an index on `InstanceId, Created` and have UserId in the `INCLUDED` list. There are quite a few ways to index data and it can take a while to find the best setup for you.